# Salvando dados com relacionamento (OneToMany) Lavarel 5.1

Tags: laravel

Boa tarde!

Criei uma aplicação em Laravel onde preciso salvar os dados de um determinado produto, ele tem um relacionamento um para n.
Gostaria de saber qual a melhor forma de fazer isso. Estou tentando da maneira abaixo porém não está dando certo, ele cria os registros das fotos e posição mas não passa os capturado no $request.

View:

```
<input type='text' name='photos[0][url]'>
<input type='text' placeholder='Posição de exibição' name='photos[0][position]'>
<br>
<input type='text' name='photos[1][url]'>
<input type='text' placeholder='Posição de exibição' name='photos[1][position]'>
```

Controller:

```
$product = Product::create($request->all());            
$photos = $request->get('photos');
$product->photos()->createMany($photos);
```

Model:

```
public function photos() {
  return $this->hasMany('Grafica\Model\ProductPhoto');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eduardo, boa tarde!
Obrigado pela resposta..
Por fim a solução foi assim:

```
<input type='text' name='product_photos[0]['url']>
<input type='text' name='product_photos[0]['position']>
```

No controller:

```
$product = Product::create($request->all());
$product->photos()->createMany($request->get('product_photos'));
```

Independente de quantos product_photos tiver ele dá certo..

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
/*
O modelo que cede a chave estrangeira que tem o hasmany o que possui a chave da entidade cedente possui belongsTo

Por exemplo:
A tabela pedidos possui a id do produto então no modelo de pedidos haverá.
*/
function produto()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\models\Produto');
}
/*
A tabela de produtos cede o id a tabela pedidos então no modelo de produto haverá:
*/
function pedido(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\models\Pedido','id_produto');
}

?>
```

Comment: Obrigaido pela resposta. Fiz isso mas não resolveu o problema, quando eu dou o createMany, os dados do 'photos' não são salvos nele..

Answer (score 0):

Eu não acredito que a função createMany exista no laravel 5.

Sugiro que leia a documentação sobre relacionamentos [na documentação oficial do laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many).

Eu indico os passos abaixo para que seja realizado o cadastro da maneira que você precisa:

1 - persistir o produto no banco, dessa forma você terá acesso ao ID do produto.

2 - deverá realizar um loop no array recebido do $request->get('photos')

3 - cada interação do loop:

3.1 - deverá ser criado um objeto de ProductPhoto

3.2 - atribuir os valores de array aos atributos do objeto criado e no campo foreignkey colocar o ID do produto criado no passo 1.

3.3 - realizar um save no objeto ProductPhoto